# Android studio: How to re run unit test automatically at file change?

Tags: android-studio, junit5

Coming from Typescript using Jest there I could send the `--watch` flag and every time I changed the test file the test will automatically run.

Is there something similar with Android Studio using JUnit5 ?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using Gradle 6.7 or higher. Adding `--watch-fs` enables Gradle's fs watcher. You might want to also include `-Dorg.gradle.vfs.verbose=true` to get more information about the virtual fs state and events it received.

Example to run tests:

`./gradlew --watch-fs -Dorg.gradle.vfs.verbose=true test`